# How do I remove "duplicate" files in batch?

Tags: files

I have a lot of files that have duplicates. The files look something like this:

```
dsc_0364_5723957929_o.jpg
dsc_0364_5294988157_o.jpg

dsc_0365_2464873748_o.jpg
dsc_0365_2853758327_o.jpg
....
```

I want to delete the second file (sometimes third) with the same prefix. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to delete the duplicate lines from the listing, or do you want to delete the duplicate-named files from the disk/filesystem?

Comment: Two questions, did you mean `bash` instead of `batch`? and If there are two or more duplicated files can you delete any of them?

Comment: I want to delete the files from the disk.

Comment: By batch I meant all at once, since I didn't want a separate command for each prefix (one command for dsc_0364 and then another for dsc_3065 etc). I can delete them manually, but that would take ages since there are over a thousand files with duplicates.

Comment: Have you considered something like `fdupes`?

Comment: @roaima Isn't that overkill? The duplicates are already known due to the names, no need for checking the contents. It might even be possible that the files are not identical and `fdupes` would fail.

Comment: @FelixJN it works. Why expend additional effort for what I suspect is a one-off process? (Your `awk` suggestion is a nice solution +1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `gawk` with `find` and `xargs`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'dsc*jpg' -print0 |
gawk 'BEGIN { RS=ORS="\0" ; FS="_" } seen[$2]++' |
xargs -0 rm
```

Note that using NUL as record separator is AFAIK [supported only in GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawk-split-records.html) (`gawk`).

Answer (score 0):

This solution works if all the files follow the same pattern: `string_string_string_string.string`. What I mean is that it's necessary to have three `_` in your filename to can get its prefix. For example, having the filename: `dsc_0360_5294988157_o.jpg` I want to get its prefix `dsc_0360`.

The following script should work:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

lastPrefix=''

for i in ./* ; do
   prefix=${i%_*_*}
   if [[ $prefix == $lastPrefix ]];then
      rm $i
   else
      lastPrefix=$prefix
   fi
done
```

With the line `prefix=${i%_*_*}` I'm getting the prefix of the filename and comparing if this one has already been set with the same prefix before, if so then it should delete the file.

You might need to change `for i in ./* ;` with your working directory: `for i in /path/to/your/working_directory ;`

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use an associative array to keep track of which filename prefixes you've already seen.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define $seen as an associative array (-A).
declare -A seen

for f in dsc_* ; do
  # derive a value for $prefix by removing the last
  # two _ sections from $f, e.g. remove '_5723957929_o.jpg'
  prefix=${f%_*_*}

  # test if "$seen"'s element for this "$prefix" is empty:
  if [ -z "${seen[$prefix]}" ] ; then
    # if it is, then we haven't seen this prefix before, so
    # we need to remember it.
    seen[$prefix]="$f"

    # optional debugging output. delete or comment out if
    # not needed.
    echo "seen[$prefix] = $f"

  else
    # Dry-run showing which files would be deleted.
    # remove the echo to actually delete it. Optionally
    # add -v for verbose output.
    echo rm -f "$f"
  fi
done
```

When run in a directory containing your sample filenames, it produces the following output:

```
seen[dsc_0364] = dsc_0364_5294988157_o.jpg
rm -f dsc_0364_5723957929_o.jpg
seen[dsc_0365] = dsc_0365_2464873748_o.jpg
rm -f dsc_0365_2853758327_o.jpg
```

If it were run without the debugging output and `echo rm -f` replaced with `rm -fv` for verbose output, it produces the following output

```
removed 'dsc_0364_5723957929_o.jpg'
removed 'dsc_0365_2853758327_o.jpg'
```

without `-v`, it deletes the files but produces no output at all.